# Latex 2 bibliographies at the end of document

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I have 2 separate bib files that I currently use like this:

```
\bibliography{bib_a,bib_b}
```

However, I would like to present them separately at the end of my article. I couldn't find useful info in other threads, hence this one. I want the numbering not disrupted and a unique name for the header of the references of bib_b. So something like this:

**References**

[1] article 1

[2] article 2

**'Unique name for references B'**

[3] article 3

[4] article 4

Any idea how to achieve this?

***Edit: added a working example below.***

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

\title{test}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Some Section}
    \ldots \cite{a1} \cite{a3} \cite{a4} \cite{a2} 

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}  
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}  
\bibliography{bib_a,bib_b}  

\end{document}
```

**bib_a.bib:**

```
@Article{a1,
  title         = {Article 1}
}

@Article{a2,
  title         = {Article 2}
}
```

**bib_b.bib:**

```
@Article{a3,
  title         = {Article 3}
}

@Article{a4,
  title         = {Article 4}
}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please provide an MWEB (Minimal Working Example with Bibliography). Is BibTeX a must or is Biblatex/Biber an option?

Comment: @cfr Thanks for the reply. I've added a MWEB, hopefully it's clear, I struggled a bit with the formatting. With regards to your question about Biblatex/Biber.. I don't mind using them, I just want the same "number" referencing style. Thanks.

Comment: This is the perfect occasion to switch to biblatex + biber ! The setup is here : https://texblog.org/2012/10/22/multiple-bibliographies-with-biblatex/